# What jQuery event method for calculating input fields on page load using PHP echo POST?

Tags: php, jquery, calculator, onload-event

I made a pretty basic input field calculator with jquery, which calculates specific html input fields and prints the total sum into input below.

It works like it supposed when jquery events: keyup, change etc. is called. However, there is sometimes a situation when I need to set the input field values from a SESSION or POST variable

Like this:

```
echo "<div class='calculate_data' data-amount='". $x[$i] ."'>". $y[$i] ."</div>";
echo "<input class='calculate_input' name='input_".$i."' type='text' value='". @$_POST['input_'.$i]."' />";
echo "<input id='total' type='text' disabled='disabled' />";
```

and then calculator should calculate these values on page load. I've tried almost every event, but the script just won't calculate:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.calculate_input').bind("click mouseover keyup change focus load on ready", function() {
        var sum = 0;

        //Sum up
        $('.calculate_input').each(function() {
            sum += Number($(this).val() * $(this).prev('.calculate_data').attr('data-amount'));
        }

        //Set the sum of all the previous fields to the #total field    
        $('#total').val(sum);
        if($('#total').val() == "NaN"){
            $('#total').val("-");
        }
    });
});
```

What jQuery event method does the task or have I done something wrong?

Comment: Sorry, the jquery was improper when I tried to strip it from other stuff. Should be better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use so many event types. You only need it on page load and change. jQuery already should run on page load, so just trigger it outside of the statement.

**UPDATE**
Changed according to your jQuery change

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.calculate_input').bind("change", function() {
        var sum = 0;

        //Sum up
        $('.calculate_input').each(function() {
            sum += Number($(this).val() * $(this).prev('.calculate_data').attr('data-amount'));
        }

        //Set the sum of all the previous fields to the #total field    
        $('#total').val(sum);
        if($('#total').val() == "NaN"){
            $('#total').val("-");
        }
    });
 $('.calculate_input').trigger('change'); //when the document is ready, trigger the change
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you expect that to happen on page load.. Trigger the event explicitly .

You can try this

```
$('.calculate_input').click();
```

Also on and ready any not events according to my knowledge..

```
$('.calculate_input').on("click mouseover keyup change focus load ",
```

Use `.on()` instead of `.bind()` to attach the events

You code should be enclosed inside the **DOM Ready** handler